# How to handle client response during Transient Exception retrying?

Tags: rest, http, exception, response, transient-failure

**Context**

I'm developing a REST API that, as you might expect, is backed by multiple external cross-network services, APIs, and databases. It's very possible that a transient failure is encountered at any point and for which the operation should be retried. My question is, during that retry operation, how should my API respond to the client?

Suppose a client is POSTing a resource, and my server encounters a transient exception when attempting to write to the database. Using a combination of the Retry Pattern perhaps with the Circuit Breaker Pattern, my server-side code should attempt to retry the operation, following randomized linear/exponential back-off implementations. The client would obviously be left waiting during that time, which is not something we want.

**Questions**

Where does the client fit into the retry operation?

1. Should I perhaps provide an `isTransient: true` indicator in the JSON response and leave the client to retry?
2. Should I leave retrying to the server and respond with a message and status code indicative that the server is actively retrying the request and then have the client poll for updates? How would you determine the polling interval in that case without overloading the server? Or, should the server respond via a web socket instead so the client need not poll?
3. What happens if there is an unexpected server crash during the retry operation? Obviously, when the server recovers, it won't "remember" the fact that it was retrying an operation unless that fact was persisted somewhere. I suppose that's a non-critical issue that would just cause further unnecessary complexity if I attempted to solve it.

I'm probably over-thinking the issue, but while there is a lot of documentation about implementing transient exception retry logic, seldom have I come across resources that discuss how to leave the client "pending" during that time.

**Note**: I realize that similar questions have been asked, but my queries are more specific, for I'm specifically interested in the different options for where the *client fits into a given retry operation*, how the client should react in those cases, and what happens should a crash occur that interrupts a retry sequence.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are some rules for retry:

- always create an idempotency key to understand that there is retry operation.
- if your operation a complex and you want to wrap rest call with retry, you must ensure that for duplicate requests no side effects will be done(start from failure point and don't execute success code).

Personally, I think the client should not know that you retry something, and of course, `isTransient: true` should not be as a part of the resource.

**Warning: Before add retry policy to something you must check side effects, put retry policy everywhere is bad practice**